# dbms_xmlgen.SETNULLHANDLING is converting special characters like & to &amp;

Tags: xml, oracle

I am using dbms_xmlgen to generate an xml document.
To handle null values, I am using dbms_xmlgen.SETNULLHANDLING. But this is converting special characters like `&` to `&amp;`.
How can I avoid this conversion, without using replace, since it will scan whole data.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is not due to the `SETNULLHANDLING` function: this is standard XML.

Consider:

```
SQL> SET DEFINE OFF
SQL> VARIABLE xml VARCHAR2(4000);
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_ctx dbms_xmlgen.ctxHandle;
  3  BEGIN
  4     l_ctx := dbms_xmlgen.newcontext('SELECT ''&'' x FROM DUAL');
  5     :xml := dbms_xmlgen.getXML(l_ctx);
  6  END;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

xml
---------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <X>&amp;</X>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

The resulting XML is well-formed. If you replace `&amp;` with `&`, the XML won't be well-formed.

---

Regarding your comment: just use `<` and `>` in your input:

```
SQL> SET DEFINE OFF
SQL> VARIABLE xml VARCHAR2(4000);
SQL> BEGIN
  2     :xml := dbms_xmlgen.getXML(
  3                 dbms_xmlgen.newcontext('SELECT ''This is <B>BOLD</B>'' x
  4                                           FROM DUAL'));
  5  END;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
xml
---------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <X>This is &lt;B&gt;BOLD&lt;/B&gt;</X>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

Comment: Ok. Even if it is not due to setnullhandling, but I want to avoid such conversion. Is there any way I can do it ?

Comment: @Payal: I don't think there is a way to prevent this kind of translation since it is needed to produce well-formed XML. You can use `replace` on CLOB but it might be cumbersome if you have several protected symbols (`<`, `>`...). You could also cast your input as RAW and translate it back when you read it (treat the content as binary). I would guess the standard way would be to modify the reader of the XML file so that it understands that `&amp;` is really `&` (the reader should expect well-formed XML too).

Comment: I want part of the text to be in bold in iReport, where I am using the xml as the input datasource. I want the xml to return a value like <My_Tag>This is &lt;B&gt;BOLD&lt;/B&gt;<My_Tag>.

Comment: @payal: See my updated answer. You don't need to prevent the conversion after all :)